# PHP-FPM not working on the Kubernetes pod after upgrade Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, kubernetes, nginx, fpm

I already wrote my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070192/php-fpm-not-working-on-the-kubernetes-pod-after-upgrade-symfony), but unfortunately no one helped me. I decided to add some research to my question and describe the problem in more detail, hoping for your help.

So, I had a project that worked fine on Symfony 4.4 (base image `php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.16`). The application is running in a Kubernetes cluster. At the time of deployment, an entrypoint is running in which migrations are performed, cache is warmed up, and php fpm is running. Everything works fine, from which I conclude that nginx, php-fpm configured correctly, all users are created correctly with the correct permissions.

Then I updated my application to Symfony 5.4. On my local machine, which emulates the prod environment, there are no problems, everything still works correctly and the entrypoint runs php fpm, nothing unusual.

However, when I deploy my new application to Kubernetes, it gives me the message `Deployment is not ready: <namespace/release-name>. 0 out of 2 expected pods are ready`. Then I go to the raised pod and look at its logs. There I see the commands from the entrypoint start to run, I see the migrations run, the cache warms up, but the command to start php-fpm - `php-fpm -F` does not run! That is, on the pod I do not see processes running for php-fpm.  I also ran the config check commands with the flag `-t` and `--dubug` to make sure the configs are configured correctly - no errors. Furthermore, the configuration is configured to output logs, but I haven't found a single error from php fpm. The `/var/log/` folder only has the `nginx` directory, there is no `/var/log/php-fpm.log` file (which is specified in the config). The `nginx` directory has files `acces.log`, `error.log`, `nginx_error.log` and `nginx_access.log` In the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` path I found an error `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client...` which is exactly what tells me that nginx cannot communicate with php-fpm. I also checked what might be blocking php fpm on port `9000`, but there is nothing specific there.

The interesting thing is that if I rollback the `composer.lock` to an older version (Symfony 4.4) the php-fpm process appears. So, I came to the conclusion that some package from `composer.json` is blocking php-fpm so that there is no feedback from it.

I attach the configs below. Help me find the cause. Or how do I find the package which blocks php fpm ? Maybe I did not configure the configs for php fpm correctly and do not see the errors it sends me ?

```
entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cd /var/www/app;

SYMFONY_ENV=prod php bin/console app:migrations:migrate -q;

rm -rf var/cache/*

SYMFONY_ENV=prod php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/console cache:warmup;

chmod -R 777 var/*;
chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/tmp;
chmod 755 bin/wkhtmltopdf;

php-fpm -F &
nginx -g 'daemon off;' &
tail -f /dev/nullenter code here
```

PHP FPM

```
php-fpm.conf
[global]

error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
daemonize = no

[www]
; if we send this to /proc/self/fd/1, it never appears
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2

clear_env = no

; Ensure worker stdout and stderr are sent to the main error log.
catch_workers_output = yes

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = [::]:9000
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 7
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 200

php_flag[log_errors] = True
php_value[display_errors] = False
php_value[error_log] = /var/log/error.log
php_value[memory_limit] = 1024M
php_value[max_input_vars] = 5000
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL
php_admin_flag[expose_php] = Off
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm.log
```

Nginx config (As for php fpm and logs):

```
default.conf
upstream php-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

    internal;
    client_max_body_size 256m;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log;
```

Comment: The problem was in the wrong `OPcahce` setting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215775/16446587