# Nginx blocks PHP FPM process

Tags: php, symfony, kubernetes, nginx, fpm

I have a project running on Symfony 4.4 in a Kubernetes cluster. In the `entrypoint.sh` file, among other things, two commands are written consecutively:

1. php-fpm -F &
2. nginx -g 'daemon off;' &

Everything was working fine.

Then I updated my project to Symfony 5.4, everything worked fine locally, but in the Kubernetes cluster PHP FPM stopped working. After a long [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185314/kubernetes-with-symfony-and-php-fpm) I found that if I commented out the second command, PHP FPM worked correctly. But what went wrong? The `nginx`, `php-fpm` configuration is the same whether it is Symfony 4.4 or Symfony 5.4. You can view the configuration here. It's taken from [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).

Why is `nginx` blocking `php fpm` somehow with the new version of Symfony?

Comment: If you're already in K8s you should strongly consider breaking FPM and nginx into separate containers in the pod. Then you'll have the benefit of knowing that the processes are not stepping on each others' toes, have separate logs, simplified container builds, etc.